# Gstreamer Record Audio and Video

Tags: audio, video, gstreamer, rtsp, recording

**Rtsp Source:**
Video: payload 97, H264
Audio: payload 96, MPEG4-GENERIC AAC

---

**Works:**
Watch Video and Listen to Audio

---

rtspsrc location=[RTSP_Server_IP] name=rtspsrc rtspsrc.
! queue ! application/x-rtp,payload=96 ! rtpmp4gdepay ! aacparse ! avdec_aac ! audioconvert ! autoaudiosink sync=false rtspsrc.
! queue ! application/x-rtp,payload=97 ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! autovideosink sync=false

---

**Doesn't Work**
Convert to MP4 file

---

rtspsrc location=[RTSP_Server_IP] name=rtspsrc rtspsrc.
 ! queue ! application/x-rtp,payload=96 ! rtpmp4gdepay ! aacparse ! avdec_aac ! audioconvert ! autoaudiosink sync=false rtspsrc. mux. 
! queue ! application/x-rtp,payload=97 ! rtph264depay ! h264parse mux. 
! mp4mux name=mux ! filesink location=test.mp4

---

**Anybody have any ideas?**

Comment: How does it not work? What happens?

Comment: Also are you sure that you want to mux the decoded audio? Finally how are you terminating the pipeline? In order to get a valid mp4 file you should use "-e" when using gst-launch-1.0

Comment: I have programmed a gstreamer project to compile and will throw the EOS into the pipeline to make it stop. If I only use video to record with mux it will work and audio but to mix them both cannot get to work.

Comment: rtspsrc location=[SERVER_IP] name=rtspsrc rtspsrc. ! queue ! application/x-rtp,payload=96 ! rtpmp4gdepay ! aacparse mux. rtspsrc.! queue ! application/x-rtp,payload=97 ! rtph264depay ! h264parse mux.! mp4mux name=mux ! filesink location=test.mp4
<br/>
This is my other one I tried and doesn't work either. What it says is mux is ignored. The one I posted for the question says rtspsrc ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rtspsrc location=[RTSP_Server_IP] name=rtspsrc 
! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! mpegtsmux name=mux ! filesink location="test.mp4" rtspsrc. 
! rtpmp4gdepay ! aacparse ! mux.